# How to enable webbrowser context menu over combobox

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, browser

WebBrowser context menu or custom context menu does not shown over combobox. How to enable custom context menu over combobox?

```
Private Sub NavigateTo(ByVal url As String)
    WebBrowser1.Navigate(url)
    WebBrowser1.ContextMenuStrip = ContextMenuStrip1   
    WebBrowser1.IsWebBrowserContextMenuEnabled = False 
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Possible things to do:

- trap windows messages and get right click event before WebBrowser control has filter them;
- cover WebBrowser control with transparent Panel
- process HtmlDocument click